# how to create a column based on multiple values of another column in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a new column based on another column. specifically if it contains a certain value.

I have done the following:

```
df['region'] = np.where(df['location'].str.contains("AK| AZ | CA | CO | HI |ID | MT | NM | NV | OR | UT | WA | WY", na=False), "west",
                     np.where(df['location'].str.contains("PA | NJ | NY | VT | NH | MA | RI | CT | ME", na=False), "northwest",
                     np.where(df['location'].str.contains("AR | AL | DC | DE | FL | GA | KY | LA | MD | MS | NC | OK | SC | VA | WV", na=False), "south",
                     np.where(df['location'].str.contains("IA | IL | IN | KS |MI | MN |MO | ND |NE | OH | SD | WI", na=False), "midwest", "international"))))
```

I am getting this:

```
 location        region

Columbia, MO    international
Maplewood, NJ   international
```

expected:

```
 location        region

Columbia, MO    midwest
Maplewood, NJ   northwest
```

I basically have a column 'location', I want to check if it contains one of the abbreviations and then create a new column for the region.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you want to assign to your `region` column if it does not contain one of those strings?

Comment: thanks you for replaying. I would assign it "international". I basically have the same code for the rest of the states. others would be International

Comment: Use `df['region'] = np.where([df['location'].str.contains("IA | IL | IN | KS |MI | MN | 
MO | ND | NE | OH | SD | WI", na=False), 'midwest', 'international')`.

Comment: Find more information about creating _conditional columns_ [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column)

Comment: thank you so much for the help! I am now not getting the expected results. I hope it gets reopened